# Detecting when a Chrome Extension popup is opened

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to wire some analytics into the `onStartup` event of my Chrome Extension per the [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onStartup). However, the event never seems to fire when the extension is opened via the icon in the browser.

Note that the `onInstalled` event in the below code fires as expected when the extension is installed, reloaded, etc.

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(details) {
  console.log('Extension installed: ' + details.reason);
});
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function() {
  console.log('Extension started');
});
```

Note I'm running Chrome v37 - the `onStartup` event has been available since v23.

Comment: Where is this code located, and what happens when you "open" your extension? The extension lifecycle is - background started once per Chrome launch, and popup (if present) is created and killed on every press.

Comment: Ah, this is in my background script, which exlains why I am not seeing anything for extension opens. To track each open, where is the proper place for this? Use an `app.run();` call?

Comment: So I assume you have a popup. Then see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25232324/chrome-browseraction-onclicked-addlistener-with-popup/25233314#25233314

Comment: That did it. If you want to post as an answer I can award it Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to invoke code when a popup is opened. This is not the same as "starting" the extension - the `chrome.runtime.onStartup` event normally fires once per browser launch.

`chrome.browserAction.onClicked` event will not fire when a popup page is set; instead, you need to execute some code in the popup page itself (and that code will be executed each time the popup is opened).

You can simply send your analytics event from the popup page itself. Or, if you prefer sending it from the background page, you just need to [message it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25232324/chrome-browseraction-onclicked-addlistener-with-popup/25233314#25233314).